# Spinnaker - Error fetching artifactory names: 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: artifactory, spinnaker

I want to use Spinnaker with JFrog Artifactory.

I've followed both documentation
https://www.spinnaker.io/guides/user/pipeline/triggers-with-artifactsrewrite/artifactory/
http://theblasfrompas.blogspot.com/2019/06/deploy-artifacts-from-jfrog-artifactory.html

```
hal config
  repository:
    artifactory:
      enabled: true
      searches:
      - name: spring-artifactory
        permissions: {}
        baseUrl: https://xxx.jfrog.io/artifactory
        repo: libs-snapshot-local
        groupId: com.example
        repoType: maven
        username: usernamexxx
        password: passwordxxx
    maven:
      enabled: true
      accounts:
      - name: spring-artifactory-maven
        repositoryUrl: https://xxx.jfrog.io/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local/
```

Once deployed when I add an automated trigger, type Artifactory I immediatly get in red the following error

> Error fetching artifactory names: 500 Internal Server Error

> http://192.168.39.83:30808/artifactory/names 500 status: 500, error:
> "Internal Server Error", message: "No value present"}

Spinnaker is running on minikube, I changed storage, hypervisor, version, ...

Please advise.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I change local-artifactory to **local-artifactory** and it worked.
I can now retrieve the builds in artifactory.